# is there a way to get SQL Server 2008 available servers without using SMO

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, smo

```
 DataTable dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
 comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

I'm using the above code to populate a comboBox with available SQL Servers but this requires me to reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo in my project.

Is there away i can display available SQL Server 2008 Servers in a comboBox with out using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx).

There used to be an issue that it did not always find all Sql Server instances on a server. I'm not sure if that is still the case.